# Create an array from a data frame, based off of conditions

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a sample dataframe like;

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'degree_awarded':['yes','no','yes','yes',
                                 'yes','yes' ,'yes','no'],
                  'avg_score':[78,87,94,55,68,76,78,8]
                })
```

| degree_awarded | avg_score |
| --- | --- |
| yes | 78 |
| no | 87 |
| yes | 94 |
| yes | 55 |
| etc. | etc. |

I'd like to separate the 'degree_awarded' column into 'degree_awarded', 'no_degree_awarded' arrays with the relevant score for example

```
degree_awarded: [78, 94, 55, etc.]
no_degree_awarded: [87, etc.]
```

but I'm not sure how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: what is the type of the output? dictionary? Series?

Comment: Yeah... are you planning any further data operations on it after as it looks like you might just be after: `df.groupby('degree_awarded')['avg_score'].agg(list).to_dict()` for now

Comment: Sorry guys, the sample table and output should have included an etc. the 68,76,78,8 should have been included. Sorry again for any added confusion. I've edited the original question, hopefully It's more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listScoreAwarded=list(df[df['degree_awarded']=='yes']['avg_score'])

listScoreNotAwarded=list(df[df['degree_awarded']=='no']['avg_score'])
```

Both these lists should work

Answer (score 0):

You can [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) the labels you want, then use [`groupby.agg(list)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html).

As Series:

```
(df
 .assign(group=df['degree_awarded'].map({'yes': 'degree_awarded',
                                         'no': 'no_degree_awarded'}))
 .groupby('group')['avg_score'].agg(list)
)
```

output:

```
group
degree_awarded       [78, 94, 55, 68, 76, 78]
no_degree_awarded                     [87, 8]
Name: avg_score, dtype: object
```

As dictionary:

```
(df
 .assign(group=df['degree_awarded'].map({'yes': 'degree_awarded',
                                         'no': 'no_degree_awarded'}))
 .groupby('group')['avg_score'].agg(list)
 .to_dict()
)
```

output: `{'degree_awarded': [78, 94, 55, 68, 76, 78], 'no_degree_awarded': [87, 8]}`

Comment: Ahh... just noticed.. it would appear in the sample output the OP provide - it looks like duplicates are dropped... However, there's no 8 in their sample output either... which is odd...

Comment: @Jon I had noticed that OP provided 2 samples a longer and shorter one but I missed the duplicated 78 (good catch!). I don't know what is expected, but there are many workarounds (aggregate to set, to dict keys, drop_duplicates before, etc.)

Comment: And a completely micro-optimisation, I'd probably go for not assigning a column for the grouping, just go with the value and then rename the index access once it's aggregated before going to `dict`... eg: `df.groupby('degree_awarded')['avg_score'].agg(list).rename(index={'yes': 'degree_awarded', 'no': 'no_degree_awarded'}).to_dict()`

Comment: So sorry, duplicates were not meant to be dropped that was careless of me. Thanks so much for all of your answers.